# SVM method cross validation , tune function

Tags: r

I have a problem in function tune, and i have this error.Please help.

Error in tune("svm", train.x = x, data = data, ranges = ranges, ...) :
formal argument "ranges" matched by multiple actual arguments

```
library(e1071)
data3$'rez'<-as.factor(data3$'rez') 
table(data3$'rez')
index<-sample(nrow(data3),floor(0.8*nrow(data3))) 
train<-data3[index,]
valid<-data3[-index,]
tuned<-tune.svm(rez~., data = train,kernel="radial", ranges=list(gamma=2^(-1:1),cost=2^(2:4)))
summary(tuned)
```

Our data is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fsce4pgwjhoo9t/train.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspecified the arguments for `tune.svm`. It should be:

```
tuned<-tune.svm(rez~., data = train,kernel="radial", gamma=2^(-1:1),cost=2^(2:4))
```

The syntax you have written would work if you did:

```
tuned<-tune(svm, rez~., data = train,kernel="radial", ranges=list(gamma=2^(-1:1),cost=2^(2:4)))
```

Comment: I have tried to change almost every argumentr in tune function. And it still not works with your sintax.Notice the Error, its confusing.  Error in newdata[, object$scaled, drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long

Comment: @StefTaki Please post some sample data. Without it, we're unable to duplicate your issue. This posted answer works using the `iris` dataset. So it must be something specific to your dataset(s).

Comment: @Lm i posted database, can u check? p.s. thanks

Comment: @StefTaki, my posted answer worked with the data you posted.